# Getting Rid/Replacing ActiveX Functions

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, cross-browser, activex

We are in the process of trying to make an old add-on that used ActiveX into a cross-browser solution (since currently only IE supports ActiveX). The only functions that are utilizing ActiveX are the `<ComRegisterFunction()>` and `<ComUnregisterFunction()>`. Is there a way to get rid of or replace these functions so that the application can be used on multiple browsers?

Also could someone explain what they do? I looked up what they were from microsoft itself, but I found it hard to understand what exactly was being registered.

Comment: Those two functions allow you to load and call the ActiveX. So, you have to  look at the code. If you removing the ActiveX calls, then you have to look at that code.  So, this is like asking what does Call MySub do. It simply calls and runs the sub - the issue is what the code as a result of that call does. So, those two functions load the ActiveX (and un-load it)- it is a question of what the ActiveX code does. So, you need to look at the ActiveX object - and decide what it does, and can you re-produce what that ActiveX  control did, or can you live without it.

Comment: It also not clear if the ComRegisterFunction is part of the markup (JavaScript) or this is a class? If this is a .net class? Then the com register functions are for registering the class object to allow consume by all windows programs. I suspect that you could well easy convert this into a web user control - that works very similar, but does not require activeX. So, if you have the source code to the activeX, then you can/should be able to re-write that activeX as a user control.  So, this all comes down to you having the source code to the ActiveX control.